# How to access elements in a child component <slot>?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

I have a component which uses named slots from `<another-component>`. I was trying to get the `<span>` by calling `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('title')` in `<another-component>`, it always returns null:

```js
  render() {
    return html`
      <another-component>
        <h2 slot="header">
          <span id="title"></span>
        </h2>
        <div slot="footer">
          ${this.renderFooter()}
        </div>
      </another-component>
    `;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shadow Root getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460850/shadow-root-getelementsbyclassname)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, i found this is by design. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Basically, you can only access a DOM element under a shadow root where it's defined no matter if it's in a `<slot>` or not.

For example, let's say in your main component, you have a component A with an element with an ID:

```html
// main component's render
<a>
  <p id="title"></p>
</a>
```

Component A uses component B, and maps its slot content to another slot in component B:

```html
// component A's render
<b>
  <p slot="header">blabla</p>
  <slot slot="content"></slot>
</b>
```

Neither A nor B can access the element via `shadowRoot.getElementById`. Only the main component can get the element by ID.